# How to create a .desktop to a C program?

Tags: command-line, bash, .desktop, c, executable

So I'm trying to execute a C terminal program just by double clicking it. I'm trying to do that through a .desktop file

- The desktop file has permission to execute as a file and it's in my   desktop.
- The program is named teste, wait for User input and it's in the /home/vithor/
- I'm Using the PopOs ( it is a "ubuntu distro" );
- I already allowed executable to launch in the nautilus configs;

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/vithor/teste
Icon=/home/vithor/Pictures/Icons/books.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
~
```

But it's not working, what am I doing wrong? Or what alternative do I have to run a C program just by clicking it?

Comment: Remove the ; after utility. Also, Pop OS is not supported here.

Comment: *But it's not working* -- What is the current behavior? Does the desktop file show the icon?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the name of the program is `teste`, and it is located at your home folder.

1. Remove `#!/usr/bin/env bash` from the first line. The first line should be `[Desktop Entry]`
2. Change the `Exec` entry to

   ```
   Exec=/home/vithor/teste
   ```
3. Change the last line to `Categories=Utility`
4. Mark the .desktop file as executable with the command `chmod +x /path/to/file.desktop`.

Now it should work when you double click it.

However, if the C program is supposed to print in the terminal and do nothing else, then it would print the results and would quickly close the terminal, and you won't be able to see anything.
In such a case, change the source so that it waits for you to enter some character before closing.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
// your code here

int a;
printf("enter any character to terminate: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
}
```

Now compile the code with

```
gcc path/to/source.c -o teste
```

Comment: Nice example of a C program. However shouldn't there be a `gcc` or `make` or `lint` command somewhere?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Of course, one needs gcc to compile this. I am assuming OP knows how to compile, since the question is about how to execute the binary `teste` with a .desktop file.

Comment: No doubt OP and you know `gcc`. Some of us don't is all :)

Comment: @wineunuuchs2unix Oh OK, I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I tried it, and it didn't work :(. I will edit the question and add more information!

Answer (score 0):

Use this .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/bash -c '/home/vithor/teste ; echo "" ; echo "Press Enter to close....." ; read'
Icon=/home/vithor/Pictures/Icons/books.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

It opens up a terminal, runs your program and after your program is done, it waits until you press Enter to close it.

BTW I've tested this and it actually works.

If this works for you, please click the Tick icon on the left of this answer to accept this answer.